# Computing the region of stability for a Runge-Kutta (Order 3) method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, runge-kutta-methods

I can't find a method on how to do this anywhere, so I'm having to ask. Thanks for any help or method you can give. I have a butcher tableau that looks like this:

\begin{array}
{c|cccc}
0\\
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{2}{3} &0 &\frac{2}{3} \\
\hline
& \frac{1}{4} &0 &\frac{3}{4}
\end{array}

I also have proved that it is a method of order three.  I now have to find the region of stability for this runge-kutta method, and sketch it. I do not understand how to do this.

P.S I have the formula:

$$ R = [\mu \; \in \; \mathbb{C} :  |Q(\mu)|<1] $$

where R is the region. Happy to answer any questions you have. This is my first time doing this so not sure how much information is needed for me to give. Thank you.

Comment: Heun's 3rd order method is explicit and has maximal order for its number of stages. This implies that $Q(μ)$ is the degree 3 partial sum of the exponential series.

Comment: I read somewhere: 'Specifically for Euler’s method, we have Q(µ) = 1 + µ, and R is a disc with center −1 and radius 1. For higher-order Taylor methods, the regions of stability can be computed similarly.' For the examples of Runge-Kutta methods I've seen I've heard that the region agrees with that of the Taylor method of the same order.

Comment: Yes, if for an explicit method $s=p$, then $Q$ is the degree $p$ partial sum of the exponential series $1+µ+\frac{µ^2}2+\frac{µ^3}6+\frac{µ^4}{24}+...$. Note that $s=p$ is only true up to order $p=4$.

Comment: Okay, so now I have |1+(h*lambda)+ (1/2)*(h*lambda)^2 + 1/6*(h*lambda)^3| <= 1. Is this correct? I have another question. After sketching this region, how do I answer this: 'At which maximum step size is the method stable for real λ?' I would really, really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: If possible, please see my newest question where I have included more details. Thank you.